# Can't declare .data in inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, raspberry-pi, raspbian, inline-assembly

Hello I have a problem where I can't seem to declare .data . I've tried various different things with my code and it always seems to break at this part

```
    asm(
       ".data\n"
       ".file:  .ascii \"/dev/mem\\000\"\n"
    );
```

I can also remove any information after the .data and it will still break at '.data'. This is done on a raspberry pi 2 with inline assembly on C. If the rest of the code is relevant let me know but I'm pretty sure it's not. Thanks for any help!

Edit: Apologies I forgot to include the error message

"ERROR: .size expression for 'method name here' does not evaluate to a constant

Comment: What is the reason to use inline assembly to basically declare a global variable as an array of characters? This could easily have been done with a global variable `char file[] = "/dev/mem";`

Comment: As for your problem, the error message doesn't match the code you show. The error message mentions `.size` which is not in your code. Also, are you sure you want to use a leading dot for the label?

Comment: Lastly, what compiler are you using? Which version of it?

Comment: Shouldn't it also be `.section .data` instead of just `.data`?

Comment: I don't have any reference to '.size' in my program at all which is why the error message confuses me and the complier is gcc (Debian 4.6.3- 14+rpi1)

Comment: I'll try the C variable the now thanks

Comment: I just tried with '.section .data' but it didn't solve anything. Thanks for informing me of the correct syntax though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't restore the section before the end of the inline assembly, and gcc generate code that relies on inline assembly not changing the current section.