# Quotation mark in inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

How can I use assembly instructions that contain quotation marks inside `asm()`?
like:

```
asm(
".section .rdata,"dr"\n"
);
```

The code above gives me this error:

```
expected ')' before 'dr'
```

Comment: You escape quotes in inline-assembly just the same way you escape them in any other string.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836769/how-to-format-an-assembly-code is the reason for asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any string literal, not just the ones required by an `asm` declaration, can contain double quotes if they are escaped. You escape them with a `\`. So when applied to your example:

```
asm(
".section .rdata,\"dr\"\n"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `"\""` to put a double quote inside a C string literal, as usual.

---

Doing what you're asking isn't necessarily 100% safe.  You can have problems like [Can't declare .data in inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809752/cant-declare-data-in-inline-assembly) if you don't restore the right section.

If you change sections inside inline-asm, then it might be safe if the inline asm statement is at the very end of the C source file.

But preferably you should use [`.pushsection`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/PushSection.html#PushSection) so you can leave the assembler in the same section you were in at the start, using `.popsection`.  Doing this automatically for an existing `.S` file might only require somewhat more complicated text processing, and still be possible with a simple algorithm.

Although you're probably safe assuming that the assembler is currently in the `.text` section at the start of your inline asm, in which case  `.section .text` at the end of your inline-asm string should be safe.  (Guessing here.)

---

This is [why multiple people have told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836769/how-to-format-an-assembly-code#comment84678810_48836769) that it's definitely better to assemble a stand-alone `.S` file separately, and link the two object files.

I guess if you're using an online compiler that only allows one translation unit, this might be a useful hack, but for anything other than one-off testing, you should just get your build system to support `.S` files instead of this ugly hack of turning compiler output into inline-asm statements.  (I assume this is compiler output, or you'd just have written it by hand.)

Comment: I have no idea what that command does. I asked about it because that line caused the first error. And it's probably better to compile the .S file separately if several people recommend it but since it involves a lot of command line options with gcc and I'm not much familiar with them I'll pass, at least until I'm good at command line area xD

Comment: @Tuhnri: No, it doesn't require a lot of command line options.  `gcc -c foo.S` works exactly like `gcc -O3 -c bar.c`, creating a `.o`.  If you don't understand what the assembler directives do, you shouldn't expect everything to work if you just stick them into `asm()` directives.  It might, it might not, and if you don't understand any of it, debugging will be very hard if it doesn't.